# PyHive connecting to Hive on Dataproc got VPC_SERVICE_CONTROLS PERMISSION_DENIED NO_MATCHING_ACCESS_LEVEL error

Tags: hive, permission-denied, google-cloud-dataproc, vpc, pyhive

I'm using `pyhive` to connect to Hive on GCP Dataproc. Queries succeed and fail intermittently. This is one of the issues. It happened during a

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db_name.tb_name
```

Client side got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 154, in write
    plus = self.handle.send(buff)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  ...
    self._cursor.execute(sql, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 356, in execute
    self._reset_state()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 266, in _reset_state
    response = self._connection.client.CloseOperation(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 651, in CloseOperation
    self.send_CloseOperation(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 660, in send_CloseOperation
    self._oprot.trans.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 143, in flush
    self._flushPlain(buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 166, in _flushPlain
    self._trans.write(struct.pack(">I", len(buffer)) + buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 161, in write
    raise TTransportException(message="unexpected exception", inner=e)
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: unexpected exception
```

Server side log contains a lot of

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 7,
      "message": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
      "details": [
        {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure",
          "violations": [
            {
              "type": "VPC_SERVICE_CONTROLS",
              "description": "enVxsuY7TYqavK8rl_fwvgr3yn4-9bneHjDTtQFvton7C03R3sHaXA"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {},
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "73.252.204.93",
      "requestAttributes": {},
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "dataproc.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.ClusterController.ListClusters",
    "resourceName": "projects/xxx",
    "metadata": {
      "securityPolicyInfo": {
        "servicePerimeterName": "accessPolicies/xxx/servicePerimeters/Production_Security_Zone",
        "organizationId": "xxx"
      },
      "violationReason": "NO_MATCHING_ACCESS_LEVEL",
      "ingressViolations": [
        {
          "servicePerimeter": "accessPolicies/xxx/servicePerimeters/Production_Security_Zone",
          "targetResource": "xxx"
        }
      ],
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.VpcServiceControlAuditMetadata",
      "resourceNames": [
        "xxx"
      ],
      "vpcServiceControlsUniqueId": "xxx",
      "accessLevels": [
        "no_matching_definitions"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "xxx",
  "resource": {
    "type": "audited_resource",
    "labels": {
      "method": "google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.ClusterController.ListClusters",
      "project_id": "xxx",
      "service": "dataproc.googleapis.com"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-03-13T08:09:35.213190134Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/xxx/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fpolicy",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-03-13T08:09:35.968888182Z"
}
```

I'm connecting from a Mac laptop behind VPN.

sasl3==0.2.11

thrift==0.13.0

thrift-sasl==0.4.2

pyhive==0.6.3

Any pointers how to fix this? Seems to be server side permission setting? Thanks!!